# Using do.call to call a list of functions

Tags: r

I am having trouble figuring out how to use `do.call` to call and run a list of functions.

for example:

```
make.draw = function(i){i;function()runif(i)}
function.list = list()
for (i in 1:3) function.list[[i]] = make.draw(i)
```

will result in

```
> function.list[[1]]()
 [1] 0.2996515
> function.list[[2]]()
 [1] 0.7276203 0.4704813
> function.list[[3]]()
 [1] 0.9092999 0.7307774 0.4647443
```

what I want to do is create a function that calls all three functions in the list at one go. from what I understand `as.call()` can be used to do this but I am having trouble connecting the dots and getting 6 uniform random draws from `function.list`.

Comment: I'm assuming your actual use for this precludes simply doing `runif(6)`?

Comment: yes, I am actually tying to run a very long list of customized functions using a factory procedure as above. I find runif helpful for the example because the output and input are easily observable.

Answer (score 12):

Did you want something like this?

```
lapply(function.list, do.call, list())
# [[1]]
# [1] 0.5777857

# [[2]]
# [1] 0.8970102 0.5892031

# [[3]]
# [1] 0.4712016 0.2624851 0.2353192
```

Comment: I was hoping for something that uses primitives, i.e. without the use of explicit for loops

Comment: Where do your functions come from?  The best solution is to make sure they're properly vectorised.  If that's not possible, an explicit `for` loop, with a pre-allocated results array should be fast enough --- most of the time will be spent inside the functions in `function.list`.

Comment: There is no primitive to do this. And lapply only loops at the c level anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
 make.draw = function(i){runif(i)}
 Map(make.draw, 1:3)
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.03442084

#[[2]]
#[1] 0.6899443 0.8896434

#[[3]]
#[1] 0.3899678 0.2845898 0.4920698
```

Comment: map is just a wrapper for sapply which has the same for loop issues. I am trying to call 40 different functions 10,000 times for a mc simulation and would rather write it in r if I have the option.

Comment: I suspect that the efficiency holdups lie in those "40 different functions" to a much greater extent that any "loop issues".

Comment: you are probably right, but I would like to know how to do this anyways for future reference. it would be nice to know how to run large batches of code sequentially without any additional loops and I am certain that you can do this with the .call procedure.

Comment: Are you talking about the `.Call` procedure? The `do.call` function offers nothing iterative. It's just a way to raise a character input to a language object and bind an argument list.

Comment: You are right, I figured it out. the each function in the plyr package is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: No ...  you got an answer on r-help to a question that did not acknowledge that you were already being offered solutions on SO that you were rejecting. Come back when you have comparative testing of the performance difference.

Comment: @honeyoak: If looping speed is a problem, try the `Ra` package (http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/ra/) and `cmpfun` from the `compiler` package.