# In R, how to make order of execution determined by vector

Tags: r

Let's say I have some variable `funcorder` and n functions `func1`,  `func2`, `func3` up to `funcn`.  If `funcorder=c(3,2,5...1)` where `length(funcorder)==n` then I want to run my functions according to `funcorder` ie.

```
func3
func2
func5
...
func1
```

If this were a smaller example, say 2 functions then I could do something like

```
if (identical(funcorder,c(1,2)) {
  func1()
  func2()
} else {
  func2()
  func1()
}
```

but this doesn't seem very elegant and definitely doesn't scale.  Is there a better way?

Comment: What about `compose(func1(), func2(), .dir = 'forward')` and change the `.dir` based on your condition?

Comment: @akrun it looks like .dir can only be "forward" or "backward".  Nothing for 3,2,5,1.  I actually thought of a way as I was typing my question but I figured I'd wait and see what else people come up with.

Comment: You can keep it in a `list` i.e. `list(func1, func2, ....)` use the index to reorder and then use `do.call(compose, ..`

Answer (score 0):

We may use `compose` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
compose(!!!list(func1, func2, func3)[funcorder], .dir = "forward")(v1)
```

where 'v1' is the object to be executed with the functions in the order specified by `funcorder`

Comment: what does the `!!!` do?

Comment: According to the docs `The big-bang operator !!! forces-splice a list of objects.`

Answer (score 0):

You can have `do.call` call the functions inside `lapply`:

```
x <- 0

add1 <- function() x <<- 10*x + 1
add2 <- function() x <<- 10*x + 2
add3 <- function() x <<- 10*x + 3
add4 <- function() x <<- 10*x + 4
add5 <- function() x <<- 10*x + 5

flist <- list(add1, add2, add3, add4, add5)
funcorder <- sample(1:5)
invisible(lapply(flist[funcorder], do.call, list()))
x
#> [1] 34512
funcorder
#> [1] 3 4 5 1 2
```

Found where I've seen this before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7773454/9463489